# "test-utils" project with maven - how to manage dependencies

Tags: maven

Let's suppose that I have a bunch of code that I need across a lot of projects, but just in tests.

So, I want to create a separated maven project for it, for example, `carlos-test-utils`, and ad it as a test dependency in my projects.

But, in my `carlos-test-utils` project, I also need JUnit. So, I add it as a test dependency, which obviously doesn't work, because I put my code in `src/main/java`.

I would like to hear which is the best way to deal with this kind of thing.

Put deps as provided?

Some dirty tricky thing to copy `.java` files across the projects?

Any other thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can manage that via the [maven-jar-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/) which should be used for such cases in the following way:

This should be done in the module/project which should provide the test classes and
the code should be put in the usual folder for test code *src/test/java* and *not* in *src/main/java*. All the dependencies your Test code needs should be added as usual dependencies with scope *test*.

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

In the project you like to use the test dependencies just use it like this:

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>groupId</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
      <type>test-jar</type>
      <version>version</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```